# Why does non greedy regexp fail in Sqlite?

Tags: regex, sqlite

Below two queries. The second group on the first query is greedy, on the latter is not.

Why does the first work and the latter doesn't?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '(Color|Material)=(\w.*)($|,)';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '(Color|Material)=(\w.*?)($|,)';
```

**EDIT** (in response to comments)

By fail I mean it crashes. It has nothing to do with the data in the table. It looks like SQLite fails parsing the command or compiling the regular expression.

Here is the output of the command as shown by the DB Browser for SQLite:

```
Result: invalid operand
At line 1:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '(Color|Material)=(\w.*?)($|,)';
```

Comment: Good question. Greediness shouldn't affect whether a regexp matches, just how which part of the string it matched.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a built-in regexp engine, you have to provide your own `regexp()` user-defined function. So the behavior of the regexp will depend on how you defined this.

Comment: So it sounds like you have one that doesn't implement non-greedy quantifiers.

Comment: As I said above, greediness is not relevant if you're just testing whether a string matches a regexp. It's only important if you're extracting the part of the string that matches, or doing a regexp replacement. Since SQLite doesn't have these operations, why do you need non-greedy regexp?

Comment: @Barmar I thought about your points, but (1) my Sqlite comes installed with Anaconda, so I assumed it would use either the Python or the Perl syntax and (2) I thought that in a sequence of greedy and non greedy groups there could be a difference. You might be right and there is no reason other than it works and I just need to go with the flow. Still... I thought I would ask, just to see if I would learn something useful here.

Comment: How about showing some data (in column `field`).  A discussion of the operators and syntax is perhaps helpful, but a lot of this is just guessing.  Show text that fails a match and text that matches!!

Comment: What do you mean by "fails" here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited the question and added some details

Comment: The regex library used behind the scenes is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, sqlite does not implement its own regular expression engine.  (See the section titled *The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, AND MATCH operators* in the [online docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).)  Instead regex support must be implemented by host software.  Thus, to understand which regex syntax is supported requires a knowledge of the library used by such host software.

The [docs page](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki) on the DB Browser website has [Regular Expressions](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Regular-Expressions) entry.  That page mentions that DB Browser uses Qt regular expression library, and this [Qt 5.0 doc page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details) in turn says it

> implements Perl-compatible regular expressions.

It has a link to [pcrepattern(3) man page](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) which has a list of supported operators/syntax.

That page lists both greedy and lazy quantifiers...

> QUANTIFIERS
>
> ```
>      ?           0 or 1, greedy
>      ?+          0 or 1, possessive
>      ??          0 or 1, lazy
>      *           0 or more, greedy
>      *+          0 or more, possessive
>      *?          0 or more, lazy
>      +           1 or more, greedy
>      ++          1 or more, possessive
>      +?          1 or more, lazy
>      {n}         exactly n
>      {n,m}       at least n, no more than m, greedy
>      {n,m}+      at least n, no more than m, possessive
>      {n,m}?      at least n, no more than m, lazy
>      {n,}        n or more, greedy
>      {n,}+       n or more, possessive
>      {n,}?       n or more, lazy
> ```

Despite the claim that Qt support Perl-compatible syntax, **the error indicates that the lazy syntax is not actually supported**, so we fall back to [Qt 4.8 docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#characters-and-abbreviations-for-sets-of-characters) which does not list any lazy construct.  However, the same page does have [a statement about non-greedy](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#notes-for-perl-users) (i.e. lazy) quantifiers.  Here's what it says:

> QRegExp's quantifiers are the same as Perl's greedy quantifiers (but see the note above). Non-greedy matching cannot be applied to individual quantifiers, but can be applied to all the quantifiers in the pattern. For example, to match the Perl regexp **ro+?m** requires:
>
> ```
> QRegExp rx("ro+m");
> rx.setMinimal(true);
> ```

Although it seemed like we were approaching a possible solution, one cannot call any special Qt method to implement non-greedy quantifiers from an SQL statement, so that was largely a dead end.  If we go back to the [pcrepattern(3) man page](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt), we see that the actual Perl regex syntax supports inline option settings, more specifically the `(?U)` option that sets the quantifier default to ungreedy (lazy).  You could try putting that option at the beginning, but I am almost certain that it will not work since the above exploration already proved that Qt (and likewise DB Browser) does not support the full Perl regex syntax.

**The final conclusion is simply that the non-greedy syntax is not supported in DB Browser for sqlite.**  (Is it broken?  Not necessarily, rather just that the particular construct is *not supported*.)  But remember that that particular regex implementation is only relevant to DB Browser.  If you are coding for sqlite in any other platform, you may have the opportunity to include another REGEXP implementation.  But that also isn't a sure thing, because it depends on what language and sqlite library you're using.

Comment: I reported it and it has already been *fixed*: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/2040